# Does unique maximum at interior point imply negative second derivative?

Tags: calculus

Suppose that a function $f$ is twice continuously differentiable on an open interval $(a,b)$, and also attains a unique maximum at some $p \in (a,b)$. Is it true that $f''(p) < 0$? If so, why? If not, feel free to assume infinite differentiabilty of $f$.

I know how to prove the other direction, but this direction is confusing me a bit. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the curve

$y(x) = -x^4 \tag 1$

for

$x \in (-1, 1); \tag 2$

then

$y(0) = 0 \tag 3$

is the unique maximum, but since

$y''(x) = -12x^2, \tag 4$

$y''(0) = 0. \tag 5$

So the answer appears to be "no".

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert! Very cunterintuitive though. So, I gues $f''(p) \leq 0$ always?

Comment: @abcd:  if $p$ is a local maximum, yes. It's easy to show that $f''(p) > 0$ implies $p$ is ***not*** a maximum.

Comment: In general, you can cook up more such examples when $f'$ has a multiple root at the point where it attains the maxima.

Comment: @Iguana:  indeed you can my friend!

Comment: @abcd This ought to be listed in your text as the Second Derivative Test.  If the second derivative is positive, a critical point is a minimum, negative means maximum, but 0 is listed as "inconclusive" for exactly this reason.